# Nested or different mongodb collections for e-commerce products with multi language?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, database-design, architecture

He there, I use to work with Relational DBS, but right now trying to implement e-commerce shop and use mongodb.

I need the product, sub-products and description (multi lang);

I prefere to separate everything by 3 collection (maybe its not a good idea because mongo use 1 collection for one entity, in my example, 3 collection for 1 entity)

```
"content": [{
        pid: 1,
        lang: "ru",
        title: "Привет"
    },
    {
        pid: 1,
        lang: "en",
        title: "Hello"
    },
    {
        pid: 2,
        lang: "ru",
        title: "Пока"
    },
    {
        pid: 2,
        lang: "en",
        title: "Bye"
    }
],
"products": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "almonds",
        "price": 12,
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "item": "pecans",
        "price": 20,
    },
],
"sub": [{
        "_id": 11,
        "pid": 1,
        "features": {
            "color": ["red"],
            "size": 42
        },
        "qt": 5
    },
    {
        "_id": 12,
        "pid": 1,
        "features": {
            "color": ["red"],
            "size": 43
        },
        "qt": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": 13,
        "pid": 1,
        "features": {
            "color": ["yellow"],
            "size": 44
        },
        "qt": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": 21,
        "pid": 2,
        "features": {
            "color": ["yellow"],
            "size": 41
        },
        "qt": 6
    },
    {
        "_id": 22,
        "pid": 2,
        "features": {
            "color": ["red"],
            "size": 47
        },
        "qt": 10
    }
]
```

Products should have sub-products in order to use filter, for example when i want to filter items i will seek into sub-product collection find all the yellow t-short for example with size 44, then i just `$group` the items by main `productId` and make `$lookup` with main products and return it.

Also in order to receive main product with description I should to do `$lookup` with `content` collection.

Is it a great idea or should i use 1 collection for `product` and `content`?

Like:

```
"products": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "almonds",
        "price": 12,
        "content": [{
                lang: "ru",
                title: "Привет"
            },
            {
                lang: "en",
                title: "Hello"
            },
        },
    ]
```

and maybe should I include sub-item also to main product, like:

```
"products": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "almonds",
        "price": 12,
        "content": [{
                lang: "ru",
                title: "Привет"
            },
            {
                lang: "en",
                title: "Hello"
            },
        },
        "sub": [{
                "features": {
                    "color": ["red"],
                    "size": 42
                },
                "qt": 5
            },
            {
                "features": {
                    "color": ["red"],
                    "size": 43
                },
                "qt": 2
            },

        ]
    ]
```

The main Question is it good idea to compare everything and don't care about size of the collection? And if so how should I do a filter on nested documents ('sub-products')(previously 'sub-products' collection was like a plain collection and I could make aggregation in order to find all items by color for example: `{"features.color": { $in: ['red'] }})` how can i manage it with nested document, and it will not be overwhelmed operation?

Comment: MongoDB data modeling is a process which involves various aspects - including the relationships between entities, size of data, size of data within each record, the important CRUD / queries operations you want to perform, etc. MongoDB document can have max size of 16 MB, and this allows denormalized data within the document. Also refer: [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question about the data model design decision of how to split up your entities/documents cannot be answered in a useful way with just the information given, but I can give you some aspects to think about for the decision.

MongoDb is a key-value store and as such is most useful if you can design your data in a way that uses mostly key-based lookups. This can be extended with creating additional indexes on document fields other than _id, which is indexed by default. Everything that is not indexed will result in [collection scans](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#:%7E:text=Without%20indexes%2C%20MongoDB%20must%20perform,of%20documents%20it%20must%20inspect.) and be very inefficient to query. Indexes can substantially increase the amount of storage required, so depending on your scenario cost may be a prohibiting factor to just index every field you want to query by later. That means when designing entities you will also have to consider estimated size of collections and the possibility to reference between collections (by guid for example).

So in order to make the right design decisions for your data model we cannot judge just based on the data schema you want to store, but rather based on the queries you are looking to perform later and the expected collection sizes / future scaling requirements. Those are aspects that you only touch very lightly in your question. For example if you plan to query all kind of complex joins and combinations of property values across all your entities, you may ask yourself if you can afford the extra storage cost of non-normalized data and additional indexes, or if a traditional (or modern) SQL-RDB, or maybe a graph database may be more suitable than a key-value store for your use case. Whereas if your database scale will be small at all times and your main concern is developer productivity these considerations may be worthless.

Your specific question about accessing "sub"-documents within an array of the parent "products" can be answered by that it is supported by using an [elemmatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). For example:

```
db.products.find({sub: {$elemMatch: {'features.size':43, 'features.color':'red'}}})
```

Please note again that these queries will only be efficient if you index the fields in your query. In case of array sub-documents that means looking into [multi-key indexes.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)

In order to acquire more knowledge for better decisioning around DB models and your questions about queries in MongoDB I recommend reading the [official MongoDB data model design guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/), the [documentation for querying arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/), as well as googling some articles on normalization and the motivation of [SQL vs noSQL](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained/nosql-vs-sql) in terms of [scaling/sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/), [ACID](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/acid-transactions) and [eventual consistency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/).

Comment: Thanks for useful links and a few clues